# jQuery .height() return 0 when visible but non-0 when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem here right opposite like others: in jQuery I cannot get height of element when it's visible, but when hidden. I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="filtering-filter-holder">
    <div id="filtering-filter-holder-inner"></div>
</div>
```

basic CSS for it:

```
#filtering-filter-holder {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 420px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #164372;
}
```

and finally, JS in document.ready():

```
$('div.filtering-filter-headline').mouseenter(function() {
    var el = $(this).parent().find('div.filtering-filter-content');

    if ($('div#filtering-filter-holder').is(':visible')) {
        $('div#filtering-filter-holder-inner').stop(true, true).fadeOut(300, function() {
            $('div#filtering-filter-holder-inner').html($(el).html());
            var height = $('div#filtering-filter-holder-inner').height();
            $('div#filtering-filter-holder').stop(true, true).animate({ height:height }, 300);
        }).fadeIn(300);
        $('div#filtering-filter-holder').stop(true, true).animate({ left: $(this).offset().left }, 300);
    }
    else {
        $('div#filtering-filter-holder-inner').html($(el).html());
        $('div#filtering-filter-holder').css({ top: ($(this).offset().top + 22), left: $(this).offset().left });
        $('div#filtering-filter-holder').fadeIn(300);
        $('div#filtering-filter-holder-inner').fadeOut(1, function() {
            var height = $('div#filtering-filter-holder-inner').height(); // not working without hidding this element
            $('div#filtering-filter-holder').height(height);
        }).fadeIn(1);
    }
});
```

If `filtering-filter-holder` is visible, then some animations are added. If not, initial setup is required - however, I'm not able to get height of filtering-filter-holder-inner if element is display: block, and I have to hide it before. I'm wondering, what I have done in bad way - as Google says, developers have problem with opposite problem.

I would like to know why I have to hide element first.

I'm able to use both, jQuery and jQueryUI, as both is loaded on page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The example is on: http://jsfiddle.net/tomis/jDWbK/

Comment: A demo on http://jsfiddle.net would be really helpful.

Comment: That is somehow problem, it's workign there. I'm including live page instead.

Comment: Sorry, tried working example on fiddle. Here it`s: http://jsfiddle.net/tomis/jDWbK

Comment: @tomis , My 2 cents, you are wasting time on reinventing the wheel like drop downs and other web components, try using a framework like jQueryUI or twitter bootstrap.

Comment: @DhruvPathak This is not complete code, it will be much more complex. But I need solve this first. I have real reason for this...